# array of lines in csv file

Tags: java, csv

I am trying to create an array of lines in a csv file.

Example csv:

```
12,13,14,15
13,14,15,16
11,12,13,14
```

Now i want my array to contain 3 strings.

I got this:

```
public static String[] postcodeRows;
public static void main(String[] arg) throws Exception
{
    //read the csv file
    BufferedReader CSVFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
            "C:\\Users\\randy\\Documents\\postcode csv\\exports\\all-groups.csv"));

    //count where we are in the csv file
    int csvLine = 0; 
    postcodeRows[0] = CSVFile.readLine(); // Insert the first line.
    // The while checks to see if the data is null. If it is, we've hit the end of the file. If not, process the data

    while (postcodeRows[csvLine] != null)
    {
        csvLine++;
        postcodeRows[csvLine] = CSVFile.readLine();
    }
    // Close the file once all data has been read.
    CSVFile.close();

}
```

Right now I get this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at postcodeCheckup.postcodePanel.main(postcodePanel.java:43)
```

Why is there a `NullPointerException` and how can I prevent this? The variable can't be `null`, that's checked by the `while` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be null, you're looking at the wrong thing. :)

The array postCodeRows is not initialized.

Check out http://mathbits.com/MathBits/Java/arrays/Initialize.htm.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your array, in your case it looks like the array needs to be dynamic.

Look into using java [arraylist](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).